# Initial commitも含め別のブランチに移したい

Tags: git, github

GitHub上に新規作成した空のリポジトリがあります。
本来は、そのリポジトリをクローンし、適当にmasterブランチにコミットし、そこからトピックブランチへ分岐させ、その上で作業し、最終的にmasterに対してPRを送るはずでした。
ですが今すべての作業をmaster上で行っていたことに気付いてしまいました。
私がやりたいのは、このmasterブランチ上のコミットを**全て**別のブランチに移し替え、その上その移し替え先のブランチがmasterから分岐していることにすることです。
可能でしょうか？
またこの状況からmasterに対してPRを送る方法が他にありましたらご教授ください。

Comment: 回答はもうついていますが、gitはブランチの中にコミットが格納されてゆくのではなく、コミットのリンクトリスト(正確にはDAG)のノードに名前をつけてブランチとかタグと呼んでるだけ、と考えればブランチ操作が理解しやすくなると思います。

Answer (score 3):

リネームしましょう。

```
git branch -m master develop   # ローカルmasterをdevelopにリネーム
git push origin :master  # リモートのmasterブランチを削除
git push --set-upstream origin develop # リモートにdevelopとしてプッシュ
```

それか、単純にブランチを作ればいいのでは？

```
git branch develop master
git checkout develop
git push origin develop
```